# How to preserve the normal alignment of equations in revtex4-2 with nofootinbib?

Tags: equations, footnotes, revtex

I've notice that `revtex4-2` documentclass with `nofootinbib` option sometimes breaks the alignment of equations. Why does it do it? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a method to avoid that behavior?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[][1-40]

A column break is somewhere here. \lipsum[][43-67]%
\footnote{The number in the equation below is misaligned.
  Without this (a bit verbose) three-line sentence the
  footnote would be a bit shorter and the issue observed
  above with misaligned formula would disappear.}
\begin{equation}
  1=1
\end{equation}
\lipsum[][71-90]
\begin{equation}
  2=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It produces [image: a pdf with misaligned formula (1)]

Note 1: the revtex version used in the above example is `revtex4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e`, the one used in Overleaf as of January 23, 2023.

Note 2: a similar question [RevTeX strange behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188698/revtex-strange-behaviour-possible-bug) had a single-line `align`, which is not an issue here.

Comment: Interesting, with the `equation` environment it seems to be tied to the lack of space between the `\lipsum` and `\footnote` macros, but using `\[ 1=1 \]` instead the lack of indentation persists with space.  Does your actual use-case have the footnote following a macro or plain text?

Comment: If you add a space and decrease (by 1) the number of lipsum-generated sentences to keep the amount of lines the same, then the issue would show up in the same way. That is, the issue seems to depend on the amount of text (impacting the position of the footnote marker and the footnote text) but not on the contents of that text.

In the actual use case the corresponding part of the tex is `... becomes\footnote{...}` followed by an equation.

Comment: Looking a bit more I wonder if this is just that in balancing the columns, the content initially gets set in a full left column which ends at the equation, and then in switching to balanced somehow the normal typesetting of the `equation` environment is interrupted and not fixed.  This could well mean it is the same underlying issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188698